# Form not submitting on enter

Tags: html, forms

I have a blog and it is powered by WordPress. It had a non-responsive theme before and today I've installed a responsive theme. I've built this theme from some free html themes, collected some peaces from other themes, modified and convert it to WordPress theme within a week and it's HTML5, CSS3 with `modernizr.js`.

Now, I have a strange problem and that is, in the `header.php` I have a search input and it suppose to submit the form on enter (default behaviour), but whenever I press enter, it doesn't submit the form. I looked in almost in every `JavaScript` files to find if there is any `keydown` or suchlike event that might preventing the submission but didn't find anything and I'm aware of all files as well. [This is the site](http://heera.it) and still now under development process, so can anyone please kindly look at this site and let me know if I've missed anything and this is the markup

```
<form method="get" id="searchbar" action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/search.php" style="margin:0 0 -10px !important;" _lpchecked="1">
    <input id="search-submit" type="submit" name="submit" />
    <input id="search-bkg" type="text" name="s" placeholder="Type and press enter.." />                   
</form>
```

The problem is that, form is not submitting on enter. Maybe I'm missing something so need help of fellows or any advise/tips to find out the problem. Thanks!

**Update :** This is the current code (after some suggestions from fellows here)

```
<form action="<?php echo home_url() ?>/search.php" method="get">
     <input id="search-submit" type="submit" name="submit" />
     <input id="search-bkg" type="text" name="s" placeholder="Type and press enter.." />
</form>
```

And this is the rendered markup in the browser

```
<form action="http://heera.it/search.php" method="get" _lpchecked="1">
    <input id="search-submit" type="submit" name="submit">
    <input id="search-bkg" type="text" name="s" placeholder="Type and press enter.." style="margin-top: 2px; display: none; width: 0px;">
</form>
```

But, no changes happened, remaining same problem.

Comment: If anyone have any clue, please let me know, I'm tired of this thing, I've spent hours but with no result. I've even hard coded the `action` but no changes happened.

Comment: Maybe I can `javaScript` to submit the form but trying to find out the real problem and proper way to submit as by default it should be submitted but finally I may use `JS` if i fail to figure out the solution.

Comment: _lpchechked attribute i thinks its illegal to start with an underline,although I don't think it should affect the address.

Comment: I've disabled `javaScript` and the form submitted, so I think that, the problem is one of my `Javascript` files, so I think I got a solution but need to find it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For future reference (if someone else faces the same problem, it's a debugging tip)

It was actually a plugin, which was taking the lead of the form submission using a `keydown` event handler and it was hard to find the code (4/5 lines) from a big file and also it was hard to find out exactly which file is doing the job. But suddenly I realized that if I disable `JavaScript` and try to submit the form using `enter` then I could be sure that there is definitely `js` event handler, which is preventing the submission. So, i did it and it worked. Finally, I removed some plugins and added one after one and found out the `script` that was preventing submission of the form. So, once I got it, I just change the code and it worked.

Comment: Thank you for this, I spent a good ten minutes searching for why a HTML form would not submit and thanks to your note I found some legacy javascript that aught to have been removed blocking the submit action.

Answer (score 1):

Something's up with the way the `PHP` is rendering the bloginfo url. Your form's action is set to `#` which I'm pretty sure you don't want if you're doing a standard get request.

Comment: Thanks mate, let me check it out, it's not suppose to be.

Comment: The action was missing but now I've added and still now same problem but thanks to point me out this.

Comment: +1 for pointing me out that the `url` was missing but problem didn't solve yet, but thanks.